# How can I pass a state prop to a template file that's used to generate pages in gatsby-node?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

**Edit:** I wound up wrapping my entire app in a context hook to deliver the state and updateState variable/hooks to the rest of the app. I'm still puzzled why the Router wildcard option didn't work but needed to keep moving forward with this.

Thanks again to @JishanShaikh for your kind answers!

---

**Original post:**

I'm building a gatsby website and app using Gatsby with a Wordpress backend.

I need to pass a state (as a prop) that I'm generating at the top of my app to a template file in /src/templates/template.js. (This is just an example name.)

I can't seem to figure this out. I was able to pass the location prop to the template file just fine by adding it to my Layout component. I'm able to access my state variable in other component files, housed in src/components, but I can't seem to pass it to the template file.

I'm using Reach router to pass most of these props. For example, I have a Profile component, and I'm able to pass state to it fine, ie:

```
       <PrivateRoute path="/app/profile" 
          component={Profile} 
          allUserInfo={allUserInfo} 
          setAllUserInfo={setAllUserInfo}
        />
```

But when I try to use Reach to pass the state to the template file, I can't get it to work. In this example the component CustomPostTypeTemplate is the page template component declared in src/templates/

```
        <CustomPostTypeTemplate
         path="/cpt/:cptSlug"
          component={CustomPostTypeTemplate}
          allUserInfo={allUserInfo} 
          setAllUserInfo={setAllUserInfo}
          
        />
```

I've also tried using a wildcard, ie:

```
     <CustomPostTypeTemplate
         path="/cpt/*"
          component={c}
          allUserInfo={allUserInfo} 
          setAllUserInfo={setAllUserInfo}
          
        />
```

**Edit: Here some some more details!**

Notes:

• I'm generating the custom pages in gatsby-node.

• For this build, I moved the template file from /src/templates/ to /src/components/, but it hasn't helped.

**thank you to anyone who reads this!**

app.js:

```
import React from "react"
import { Router, Route } from "@reach/router"
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const [allUserInfo, setAllUserInfo] = useState("");

 return (
        <Layout 
          location={location}
          allUserInfo={allUserInfo} 
          setAllUserInfo={setAllUserInfo}
          >

          <Router>

            <Custom
             path="/custom/*"
              component={Custom}
              allUserInfo={allUserInfo} 
              setAllUserInfo={setAllUserInfo}

            />

</Router>
</Layout>
```

Custom.js -- /src/components/Custom.js

```
imports

const Custom = ({ allUserInfo, setAllUserInfo, location, data: { post } }) => {

console.log(allUserInfo);

return (

)
export default Custom
```

gatsby-node.js:

```
const createIndividualCustomPages = async ({ customs, gatsbyUtilities }) =>
  Promise.all(
    custom.map(({ custom }) =>

      gatsbyUtilities.actions.createPage({
      
        path: custom.uri,
        slug: custom.slug,

        // use the blog post template as the page component
        component: path.resolve(`./src/components/Custom.js`),

        // `context` is available in the template as a prop and
        // as a variable in GraphQL.
        context: {
          // we need to add the post id here
          // so our blog post template knows which blog post
          // the current page is (when you open it in a browser)
          id: custom.id,


          

        },
      })
    )
  )
```

Comment: One way to pass state to a template file is by using pageContext. You can pass data to the pageContext object in the createPage action in gatsby-node.js. Then, you can access the data in your template component via the pageContext prop.

Comment: @JishanShaikh Thanks for that! I'm not sure if that would get me there, because the state I'm loading involves me hitting a Wordpress endpoint to gather data. When my users log in, I authenticate with Firebase and create a new user in Wordpress, then I load their info into state. 

I'll keep digging -- thank you again!

Comment: In that case, you could also consider using the `useEffect` hook in your template component to fetch the data when the component mounts. You can then store the data in state using the `useState` hook and use it in your component. I can provide a code example if you really want it?

Comment: Hey, I would deeply appreciate it, thank you!

Comment: Okay, I've got a workaround for now by creating a new state in the Custom template component. But I'll keep noodling for a way to pass this down from the top.

Answer (score 0):

Pass allUserInfo and setAllUserInfo as props to the Template component using React Router, you can do so like this:

```
import { Router } from "@reach/router"
import Template from "../templates/template"

// ...

const App = () => {
  // Replace with your own logic for managing allUserInfo state
  const [ allUserInfo, setAllUserInfo ] = useState(null)

  return (
    <Router>
      <Template
        path="/cpt/*"
        component={Template}
        allUserInfo={allUserInfo}
        setAllUserInfo={setAllUserInfo}
      />
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Then, in your Template component, you can access these props like this:

```
import React from "react"

export default function Template({ allUserInfo, setAllUserInfo }) {
  // You can access allUserInfo and setAllUserInfo here
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Your template code */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: No kidding, that's almost exactly how I have it set up. I'm declaring the template as a const, not a function, ie:
***
const CustomPostTypeTemplate = ({ allUserInfo, setAllUserInfo, location, data: { post } }) => {

***

Let me look over this again. Also, I'm using Reach router -- would that make a difference? **thank you again**

Comment: Yes, I tried setting it up just like you did. Also, edited the post for reach/router. And, you don't have to call me sir :) Let me know how you proceed.

Comment: haha, you got it! okay, let me review my code. I thought maybe I'd forgotten to export the CPT template, but I did. I'll respond shortly. huge thanks again!

Comment: Hello! I tried again, but it's still not working for some reason. I'm going to take a crack at React Context to see if I can make this alluserinfo state more globally accessible. thank you again for your responses!!!